Rank condition in matrix powers

Let $n \geq 2$. Determine $m \in \mathbb{N}$ for which there exists $M \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $$\text{rank}(M^k) + \text{rank}(M^{n-k}) = m,$$ for any $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n - 1\}$.

Some ideas (Any help in writing a complete and rigorous proof is appreciated it):
Case 1: $M = I$.
If $M$ is the identity matrix $I$, then for any power $k$, we have $M^k = I$. The identity matrix has full rank, i.e.,
$$\text{rank}(M^k) = \text{rank}(I) = n \quad \text{ for all } k.$$
Thus, for any $k$, we get
$$\text{rank}(M^k) + \text{rank}(M^{n-k}) = n + n = 2n.$$
So in this case, $m = 2n$.
Case 2: $M$ is a nilpotent matrix.
Consider a matrix $M$ that is nilpotent, meaning $M^n = 0$ for some $n$. Specifically, take the matrix $M$ to be the $n \times n$ Jordan block with $0$s on the diagonal (a typical example of a nilpotent matrix).
For such a matrix, the ranks of the powers $M^k$ decrease as $k$ increases. For small powers of $M$, $M^k$ may still have nonzero rank.
However, for large enough $k$, specifically for $k \geq n$, we have $M^k = 0$, so $\text{rank}(M^k) = 0$.
This case suggests a more complicated situation where the sum of the ranks of $M^k$ and $M^{n-k}$ varies depending on $k$, but generally the sum is strictly less than $2n$.
From the two cases, we observe the following general behavior:
If $M$ is the identity matrix, the sum of the ranks is $2n$ for all $k$. If $M$ is nilpotent, the sum of the ranks is strictly less than $2n$. Thus, a reasonable conjecture is that the maximum value of $m$ occurs when $M$ is the identity matrix, and in that case, $m = 2n$.
To prove that $m = 2n$ is the only value that works, we proceed by contradiction. Assume there exists some $M$ such that
$$\text{rank}(M^k) + \text{rank}(M^{n-k}) \neq 2n.$$
This implies that for at least one $k$, the sum of ranks is strictly less than $2n$, which contradicts the fact that the maximum possible rank of any matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $n$. Therefore, the sum of ranks cannot exceed $2n$.
Hence, $m = 2n$ is the only solution.

You have only proven that $m=2n$ ist the maximal $m$ with this property, but it is not the only one. Consider the case $n=2$ and choose $M$ to be any matrix of rank $1$. Then $k$ can only be $1$ and you get that $m=2$ is possible.

After some thinking: I think all even between $0$ and $2n$, as well as $n$ should be possible values for $m$.

@Tzimmo do odd numbers work?

Please do not let your notation do double duty. Is $n$ the dimension of the space, or $M^n = 0 $?

@CalvinLin sorry for the confusion. n is the dimension of the space.

Please edit your post accordingly. The Case 2 is a mess to read.

If $n$ is odd, $m=n$ is an odd number that works. I think your nilpotent case shows that. I don't believe there are other possibilities for odd numbers.

@Tzimmo I’m having trouble in proving that other odd numbers don’t work.

$\def\ge{\geqslant}\def\le{\leqslant}\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$For any such $M \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, define$$
r_k = \rank(M^k) \quad (1 \le k \le n - 1).
$$
If $n = 2$, then $m = 2r_1 \in \{0, 2, 4\}$ with obvious constructions.
Now assume that $n \ge 3$, then $\{r_k\}$ is decreasing. For $2 \le k \le n - 2$,$$
2r_k = \rank(M^k) + \rank(M^k) \le \rank(M^{k + 1}) + \rank(M^{k - 1}) = r_{k + 1} + r_{k - 1}
$$
by the Frobenius inequality, thus $\{r_k\}$ is convex. Note that $r_k + r_{n - k}$ is constant, so $\{r_k\}$ is known to be linear.
Case 1: $r_1 = r_2$. Now that $\{r_k\}$ is constant and $0 \le r_1 \le n$, so $m$ is an even number and $0 \le m \le 2n$.
Construction: For any $0 \le r \le n$ and $m = 2r$, take $M = \begin{bmatrix} I_r \\ & O_{n - r} \end{bmatrix}$.
Case 2: $r_1 = r_2 + 1$. In this case, $r_k = r_1 - k + 1$ for $1 \le k \le n - 1$, and $r_{n - 1} \ge 0$ implies that $n - 2 \le r_1 \le n$. If $r_1 = n$, then $M$ is invertible and $r_2 = r_1$, a contradiction. Hence, $r_1 \in \{n - 2, n - 1\}$.
Note that $m = 2r_1 - n + 2$, so $m \in \{n - 2, n\}$.
Construction: Take$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ && \ddots & 1 \\ &&& 0 \\ &&&& 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ or } \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ && \ddots & 1 \\ &&& 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Case 3: $r_1 \ge r_2 + 2$. Analogous to Case 2, $r_k \le r_1 - 2k + 2$ for $1 \le k \le n - 1$, and $r_1 \le n - 1$, thus$$
r_{n - 1} \le (n - 1) - 2(n - 1) + 2 = 3 - n,
$$
and $n \ge 3$ implies $n = 3$, $r_1 = 2$, $r_2 = 0$. However, the Frobenius inequality shows that$$
4 = \rank(M) + \rank(M) \le \rank(M^2) + \rank(I_2) = 2,
$$
a contradiction.
Therefore, the range of $m$ is $\{2r \mid r \in \mathbb{Z},\ 0 \le r \le n\} \cup \{n - 2, n\}$.

What are $r_1$ and $r_2$

@math.enthusiast9 $\operatorname{rank}(M)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(M^2)$.

Preamble: My point in the comments to OP about not letting the notation do double duty, is that it obscures what is going on. OP essentially has the ideas for the solution, and I'm essentially repackaging them.
Solution:  Consider the Jordan blocks of $M$: $J_1, J_2, \ldots$.
For non-zero eigenvalues, the rank of $J_j^k$ stays the same.
For eigenvalues of 0, the rank of $J_j^k$ drops by 1 for each increase in $k$, till the dimension of $J_j$.
Let $r_i$ denote the rank of $M^k$, then $r_i = \sum rank (J_j ^ i)$. Thus, we have $$r_0 - r_1 \geq r_1 - r_2 \geq \ldots \geq r_{n-1} - r_{n}. $$
This means that $r: \{1, \ldots n \} \rightarrow \{0, 1, \ldots n \}, r(n) = r_n$ is a convex function.
Since we are given  $ r_k + r_{n-k} = m$, the convex function is actually linear on the domain.
Thus we have the following cases, constrained by the range:

$r_k$ is a constant: This gives $r_k + r_{n-k} = 2m'$, with an obvious construction.
$r_k = n-k$: This gives $r_k + r_{n-k} = n$, again with an obvious construction.
$r_k = n+1 - k$: This gives $r_k + r_{n-k} = n+2$. However, this implies $r_1 = n, r_n = 1$, which is a contradiction.  [If $rank (M) = n$, then $rank (M^i ) = n$. ]  Thus there are no solutions here.


Can you please explain the part in why the function is convex and linear and how does that imply the 3 cases?

@math.enthusiast9 Can you please explain what you don't understand about those 3 parts (and why you accepted the answer if you didn't understand)? That will allow me to tailor my explanation to what you know.

When I first looked at it it seemed clear but when I looked the second time I didn’t really understand the function part. Sorry for causing this inconvenience.

1/ How does the inequality imply that the function is convex? 2/ what convex functions satisfy $r_k + r_{n-k} = m$? Why must it be linear? 3/ Condition on what the slope and constant term is. Can the slope be 1? -2? Why, or why not?

Is it possible to find a different approach using inequalities?

Well, this approach is essentially inequalities, so yes. I'm just using fancy terms to hide all of the work. $\quad$ Show that the condition of 1/ $r_k + r_{n-k} = m$ and 2/ $r_0 - r_1 \geq \ldots r_{n-1} - r_n$ implies that $r_k = a + bk$.
